# Mapping values to a column from a Collection? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write values to a column.
The values come from a Collection.
On each row, I want to concatenate columns M and N, and the concatenated string will match one of 12 keys in the Collection.
With that key, I want to write the value from the Collection into column O.

Data:

```
M         N         O
Business  Check
Personal  Check
Business  Check
Business  Check
```

Expected output:

```
M         N         O
Business  Check    Business Checks
Personal  Check    Other Checks
Business  Check    Business Checks
Business  Check    Business Checks
```

Code:

```
    Public Sub GiftSourceDictionary()
  
    Dim collGiftSources As New Collection

        collGiftSources.Add "Business Checks", "BusinessCheck"
        collGiftSources.Add "Other Checks", "PersonalCheck"
        
        
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' MsgBox LastRow
    ActiveSheet.Range("O1") = "Gift Source"
    ActiveSheet.Range("O2:O" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&RC[-1]"
```

So this works, so far. It concatenates M and N, puts them into O.
But how in the world do I do the lookup/map/replace? (I don't even know the right name, that's probably part of the problem, ha.) How do I get the Collection value into each row now that I have the Collection key in each row?

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("O2:O" & LastRow) = collGiftSources()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Read the column with the keys into a VBA array, then use a for each loop to iterate over the array.  The values generated by the array are the keys for the collection.  Put the values read from the collection into a scripting.dictionary (use .count as the key).  Then when the array has been processed put the array obtained from the .Items of the scripting dictionary into the appropriate column in excel.

Comment: @SJR - collections can have keys...  https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/#Adding_Items_Using_a_Key

Comment: You have to use a loop, but you can do it in a single loop - no need to populate ColO and then look up the value from your Collection - just do it all in one step inside the loop.